# The best place to exercise Linear Algebra or Calculus?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, reference-request

Could anyone tell me some good website for exercising Linear Algebra or Calculus?

Comment: Try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra).

Comment: Thx good idea :D But I'm also looking or some specialized websites on excercising :)

Comment: @Itachi Try Khan academy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Paul's Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/) for explanations and exercises spanning Calculus I, II, III.

See the Khan Academy for tutorials and exercises covering [Calculus](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus) and [Linear Algebra](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra).

Those are great places to start!

Another interesting site for learning and practicing both Calculus and Linear Algebra is Temple University's [*Calculus on the Web* (COW)](http://cow.math.temple.edu/). It's much broader than mere Calculus (broken into I, II, III). The index of topics/subjects covered includes Precalculus, Calculus I, II, III,  Linear Algebra, Number Theory, and Abstract Algebra. Each subsection of an overarching subject is broken down into topics and subsections of those topics, providing modules to progress through

Comment: Thank you vey much for all of these links :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A good site for linear algebra is www.yutsumura.com this has interesting problems with worked solutions.  Some are fairly straight forward but others require more thought. The site is called problems in mathematics.

Just realised this was an old post but still it's a good site.